# Reusing MemoryMappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio, memory-mapped-files, nio2

I read a file into a `MappedByteBuffer`:

```
MappedByteBuffer buffer = FileChannel.open(file, StandardOpenOption.READ)
    .map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, Files.size(file))
    .load();
```

And write it to an `OutputStream`:

```
Channels.newChannel(getOutputStream())
    .write(buffer);
```

However, I can only do this one, presumably because the `ByteBuffer` "current location" is at the end of the buffer.

So what is the recommended way to handle the fact I wish to have multiple threads use this memory mapped file?

Comment: Rewinding is one thing, but this isn't related to the synchronization issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`rewind()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#rewind--):

> Rewinds this buffer. The position is set to zero and the mark is discarded.
>
> Invoke this method before a sequence of channel-write or get operations, assuming that the limit has already been set appropriately.

```
Channels.newChannel(getOutputStream()).write(buffer);
buffer.rewind();
// ...
Channels.newChannel(getOutputStream()).write(buffer);
buffer.rewind();
// ...
```

**Please note that `ByteBuffer` is not a thread-safe structure.**

You best option is probably to make a copy of the `ByteBuffer` for each thread so that it can be read concurrently:

```
// in thread 1
ByteBuffer duplicate = buffer.duplicate();
// ...
// in thread 2
ByteBuffer duplicate = buffer.duplicate();
// ...
```

Comment: Looks like duplicate was the method I was after, I wrongly assumed it was a deep copy.